# How to obtain a mean of values of two columns that have a same id?

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm having trouble dealing with this challenge. Considering the following data, I would like to obtain a mean of two values (variable x) of two columns with an identical value in the other two different columns (id and z), creating a new variable.

```
id <- c(32,32,36,36,40)
z<- c(1,1,2,3,4)
x <- c(10,5,15,10,10)
y <- c(8,4,12,6,15)
data <- data.frame(id,z,x,y)
```

In this example, the repeated id is 32 and the repeated value in z is 1. So, I would like to have this result:

```
id <- c(32,32,36,36,40)
    z<- c(1,1,2,3,4)
    x <- c(10,5,15,10,10)
    y <- c(8,4,12,6,15)
new <- c(7.5,15,10,10)
    data <- data.frame(id,z,x,y,new)
```

Note that the id equal to 36 does not considered because the equivalent rows in z are not equal. In my original dataset, the variable z would be the time. I sincerely hope that this question has been straightforward and someone can help me.

Comment: Looks like a group by mean `library(dplyr);data %>% group_by(id, z) %>% summarise(new = mean(x), .groups = 'drop')`

Comment: You have `7.5` for the first value yet you have 15 for teh second value. Why that? Also what if there were 3,4, etc?

Comment: Using your suggestion I achieved the result, akrun!